# CherryPy Autoloader dies with bcrypt

Tags: cherrypy

I have pure project on CherryPy and want AuthTool to use bcrypt module for password processing.

But when I put "import bcrypt" line into AuthTool.py the CherryPy tells me:

```
[17/Nov/2017:17:55:57] ENGINE Error in background task thread function <bound method Autoreloader.run of <cherrypy.process.plugins.Autoreloader object at 0x0000026948C82E80>>.
AttributeError: cffi library '_bcrypt' has no function, constant or global variable named '__loader__'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\plugins.py", line 519, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\plugins.py", line 651, in run
    for filename in self.sysfiles() | self.files:
  File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\plugins.py", line 635, in sysfiles
    hasattr(m, '__loader__') and
SystemError: <built-in function hasattr> returned a result with an error set

Exception in thread Autoreloader:
AttributeError: cffi library '_bcrypt' has no function, constant or global variable named '__loader__'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\plugins.py", line 519, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\plugins.py", line 651, in run
    for filename in self.sysfiles() | self.files:
  File "C:\Users\Serge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\plugins.py", line 635, in sysfiles
    hasattr(m, '__loader__') and
SystemError: <built-in function hasattr> returned a result with an error set
```

After that everithing works fine but Autoloader. I have bcrypt (3.1.4) and CherryPy (11.1.0).

Can I do something to fix this issue this autoreloader? Merci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable the autoloader. Set 'engine.autoloader.on' to False. Of course you will loose auto loading when monitored files are changed and thus you'll need to manually restart the server on each change. Another way would be to put the server in production mode. See available mode and what they do at: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/config.html#id14

BTW: I am seeing a similar issue with cherrypy (13.0.0) and cryptography (2.1.4)

Comment: The issue has been resolved by updating cffi to the latest version.